# Prove two values are equal from case statement

Tags: pattern-matching, typechecking, idris, unification

The following example uses `Data.Bin` from the [`Bi` package](https://github.com/sbp/idris-bi):

```
import Data.Bin

foo : (x, y : Bin) -> Dec (binCompare x y = LT)
foo x y = case binCompare x y of
    LT => Yes (C1 ?hole1)
    EQ => ...
    GT => ...

:t ?hole1
binCompare x y = LT
```

How can I get a proof that `binCompare x y = LT` when handling the `LT` case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [view](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/views.html) instead of a `case`:

> Since types can depend on values, the form of some arguments can be determined by the value of others.

So the below version works as expected:

```
foo : (x, y : Bin) -> Dec (binCompare x y = LT)
foo x y with (binCompare x y)
  foo x y | LT = Yes Refl
  foo x y | EQ = ?q_2
  foo x y | GT = ?q_3
```